# I've been trying to migrate to my database, but get errors

Tags: django-models

im getting an error with migrating to my database.
The error is ' (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.'

```
STATUS = (('active', 'active'), ('inactive', 'inactive')),
LABEL = (('new', 'new'), ('popular', 'popular'))  

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS, max_length=30)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove comma from first line

```
STATUS = (('active', 'active'), ('inactive', 'inactive')),
```

This line should be converted to this

```
STATUS = (('active', 'active'), ('inactive', 'inactive'))
```